# How can I use sudo within a function?

Tags: bash, sudo, function

I have written a function which acts in a similar way to `tee` but also pre-pends a datestamp. everything works fine except when i want to output to a file which is only root writable (in my case a logfile within `/var/log`). I've simplified the following code snippet to just include the bits which are not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script ~/test_logger.sh
logfile=/var/log/test.log
logger()
{
    while read data
    do
        echo $data >> $logfile
    done
    return 0
}
sudo ls ~ | logger
```

it works fine if i run the whole script like so `sudo ~/test_logger.sh` but i can't always do this since i want to use the logger function in files like `~/.bash_logout` which are run automatically. i've tried putting `sudo` in front of the echo in the while loop but this does not work. any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's generally bad practice to put `sudo` in a script.  A better choice would be to call the script with `sudo` from `~/.bash_logout` or wherever else you want to use it, if you must, or better still just make `/var/log/test.log` world-writable.

Comment: yes! i put the whole script into a new file `test_logger.sh`, made it executeable, then ran it from `~/.bash_logout` like so: `sudo ~/.bash_logout`. works great :)

Comment: "it's generally bad practice to put sudo in a script." If the script also does operations which do not require root access, then the opposite is true - you would be breaking the principle of least privilege by unnecessarily performing them as root. In this case, elevating only for the parts that require it is completely appropriate.

Comment: In the OP case, only the part that is writing to the log file needs to run as root. Thus, it could be executed as `sudo sh -c 'cat >> /var/log/test.log'` or `sudo tee -a /var/log/test.log > /dev/null`, with the rest of the script running as the current user.

Answer (score 8):

as you've  found, `sudo command >out` doesn't work because 'command' is run by sudo, but '>out' is a function of the shell, not 'command'.  So, you need to escalate the shell itself:

```
sudo sh -c "echo $data >>$logfile"
```

note that you want to be really, really sure what's in $data doing this:

```
~$ export data='good; touch /tmp/reallybad'
~$ echo $data
good; touch /tmp/reallybad
~$ sudo sh -c "echo $data>>/tmp/happy"
good
~$ ls /tmp/happy /tmp/reallybad
/tmp/happy  /tmp/reallybad
```

hence simon's warning.

Comment: ah thanks for clarifying the possibilities of [pipe-injection?]. i think the way i ended up doing it (see the comment under simon's solution) is safe since there is no opportunity for anyone to splice extra commands into my ~/.bash_logout file (unless the entire system is already compromised obviously)

Comment: Remember to quote your variables when passing them to a shell. What if `$data` happened to contain `foo ; rm -rf /`? Fix: `sudo sh -c "$(printf -- 'echo %q >> %q' "$data" "$logfile")"`

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` does not work in the way you might think when you use redirection or pipe operators. The stream change is not executed with `sudo` permissions. This is why

```
sudo echo foo >> bar
```

will not work if bar is only root-writable.

When you run the script under `sudo`, everything in the script gets superuser permissions so it works correctly in that circumstance.

A workaround is to do this to make sure the writing command is run under `sudo`:

```
sudo echo foo | sudo tee bar > /dev/null
```

Bear in mind, however, that this does not append to the file. It overwrites the file.

Comment: this doesnt work for me - i tried your second command like so `sudo echo hi | sudo tee /var/log/test.log > /dev/null` but it just continuously prompts for the sudo password.

Comment: Do you have sudo set-up to prompt for password every time it is used? My configuration allows continuous use of sudo as long as it was successfully used in the last 2~3 minutes so it only prompts for the sudo before the pipe.

Comment: `tee -a` appends

Answer (score 1):

You are *sudo*ing just the `ls` command, but not `logger`. Bash doesn't (and shouldn't) know what `sudo` does, so it just pipes two commands. The first one is `sudo` and the second one is `logger`. No matter if you *sudo* `ls`, `logger` won't.

You should *sudo* `logger`, but it won't work because it is a Bash function instead of an executable to be executed by `sudo`.

**BEWARE**: `ls | sudo logger` will invoke `/usr/bin/logger` if it is installed in your system. Remember: `sudo` doesn't know about Bash functions.

I'd suggest you adding the user invoking your script to the file owner's group so you're able to write to it without special privilege escalation.

Plus, efficiency sake, you are opening and closing the log file for every line read. You can do it only once for the entire logging process:

```bsh
function logger() {
  while read data
  do
    echo "$data"
  done
  return 0
} >>"$logfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you take a look at the man page of sudo you can see examples of how to use it in the scripts... the -c option lets execute a command.