# How to cd to a Windows file share?

Tags: linux, command-line, osx, samba, file-sharing

At work, I spend a lot of time manipulating files on a networked computer that's running SME Server (but that's set up for Windows filesharing, if that somehow makes a difference).

I have been wondering how to cd to the network drive's root from bash so that I don't have to keep calling up Finder / nautilus every time I want to copy a file. Any suggestions?

In Ubuntu, I connect to the drive as a Windows share via Places - Connect to Server. In OSX, well, I logged in to the drive once, and it just shows up in Finder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OS X look for your share name under /Volumes (it may have a "-digit" at the end if you have many mounts with the same name). The same goes for mounted CD/DVDs and disk images.

Answer (score 8):

While technically using Samba, Nautilus uses gvfs, which uses FUSE to mount the SMB share using libsmbclient, you aren't actually mounting the filesystem as you would with the `mount` command.  When you use Nautilus with SMB mounts, a background process `gvfsd-smb` is started.  You can access the mountpoint in ~/.gvfs/, where there's a directory in there with a name based on the mount settings you used to connect.

Check out /proc/mounts to see the details of the gvfs-fuse-daemon's mountpoint.

Comment: It appears that instead of using `~/.gvfs`, samba (fuse) now uses `/run/user/$USER/gvfs/`. This is on a Fedora 17 box as of July 2012.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way is to mount the share using [SAMBA](http://www.samba.org/). After installing samba you can mount the share as follow:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=secret //server.com/share /mount/point
```

There is [a guide](http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susesambacifs.html) for openSUSE that appears via Google. See `man mount.cifs` for more options.

Comment: Note that if you've connected to the server via Places - Connect to server, you should be able to open a terminal in the folder from nautilus. Gnome uses samba behind the scenes, and mounts the share just as phunehehe suggests above

Comment: In ubuntu, this command requires sudo. I want it in a script. Is there a way to authenticate it once and then let it run with sudo every other time?

Comment: @mouche How about running with `sudo script`? See [this answer to another question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8727/how-can-i-use-sudo-within-a-function/8730#8730)